# can't import spacy in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, spacy

i'm using anaconda environment, i've installed `SpaCy` lib, when i import this lib in terminal (spacy) it works with no error.

[image: importing spacy by terminal]

but when i use jupyter notebook in the same environemnt does'nt work, and shows this error:

```
  ***---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-76a01d9c502b> in <module>
----> 1 import spacy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'***
```

can anyone help with this error!

Comment: Are you using the same environment in terminal and Jupyter-notebook if yes then restart your kernel in jupyter notebook

Comment: Sometimes you think you're using the same environment in a Jupyter notebook as out of it but you're not. This thread has some notes on debugging a situation like that. https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7435